# WKWebview not rendering .doc file but renders pdf/png/jpeg?

Tags: ios, swift, file

When trying to load a different file type (eg. PDF, PNG, JPEG), it works perfectly.
Also tried loading the .doc data into a `UIWebview` and it also works fine. I am getting the data from a server using JSON encoded to Base64.

```
let webview = WKWebView() 
webview.load(data, mimeType: "application/msword", characterEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)
```

Has anyone faced this issue as well?
The file should not save locally.
It is the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Quicklook for this, it is native feature of iOS:-

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import QuickLook

class ClassQuickLookFilePreviewHandler {

static let shared = ClassQuickLookFilePreviewHandler()

var url: URL?
var tempURL: URL?

func previewFile(vc: UIViewController, url: URL, fileName: String) {
    let previewController = QLPreviewController()
    self.url = url
    previewController.dataSource = self
    previewController.view.tintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#ff3366")
    tempURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    previewController.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            //  in case of failure to download your data you need to present alert to the user and update the UI from the main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to download the pdf!!!", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                vc.present(alert, animated: true)
            }
            return
        }
        // write the downloaded data to a temporary folder or to the document directory if you want to keep the pdf for later usage
        do {
            try data.write(to: self.tempURL!, options: .atomic)   // atomic option overwrites it if needed
            // you neeed to check if the downloaded data is a valid pdf
            // and present your controller from the main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                vc.present(previewController, animated: true)

            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        }.resume()
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}
}

extension ClassQuickLookFilePreviewHandler: QLPreviewControllerDataSource {
func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
    return tempURL! as QLPreviewItem
}
}
```

Usage:-

```
ClassQuickLookFilePreviewHandler.shared.previewFile(vc: self, url: URL(string: ?*documentURL)!, fileName: ?*documentFileName)
```

Hope it helps :)